# How can I form this DateTime logic to increase the current time by 45 minutes

Tags: c#

I am to fill a ddl at run time.

What I actually need to do is pick up the current time from the system (in 24-hour format).
Then I need to round it up to a 15 min slot, so if the time is `13:23` it will become `13:30`; if it is `13:12` then it should become `13:15`.

Then I want to add 45 minutes to it, and 13:15 becomes 14:00.

I am trying to achieve it like this

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
string hr = d.ToString("HH:mm");
string mi = d.ToString("mm");
```

Could somebody tell, either I have to write all logic or DateTime can provide some feature 
to format it like this?

Comment: This should get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029353/c-sharp-round-up-time-to-nearest-x-minutes , once you get the rounding part you have `AddMinutes`  available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick for you:

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
d = d.AddSeconds(-d.Seconds).AddMilliseconds(-d.Milliseconds)

if (d.Minute < 15) { d.AddMinutes(15 - d.Minute); }
else if (d.Minute < 30) { d = d.AddMinutes(30 - d.Minute); }
else if (d.Minute < 45) { d = d.AddMinutes(45 - d.Minute); }
else if (d.Minute < 60) { d = d.AddMinutes(60 - d.Minute); }

d = d.AddMinutes(45);
```

Comment: Maybe first a `d = d.AddSeconds(-d.Seconds).AddMilliseconds(-d.Milliseconds)` to reset those parts?

Comment: @HansKesting, that would probably be a good reset. I'll add that, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

```
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

        //Add your 45 minutes
        d = d.AddMinutes(45);

        //Add minutes to the next quarter of an hour 
        d = d.AddMinutes((15 - d.TimeOfDay.Minutes % 15) % 15);

        //Show your result
        string hr = d.ToString("HH:mm");
        string mi = d.ToString("mm");
```

Comment: Your code to add the minutes to the next quarter of an hour is faulty. When the minute amount is 0 it will still add 15, despite being a quarter already.

Comment: Thank you for correcting it. That's even better than my solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` in C# has a function for adding any increment to the current `DateTime` object. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx) is a reference to the specific function for minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

DateTime rounded;
if(d.Minute % 15 ==0)rounded = d;
else DateTime rounded = d.AddMinutes(15 - d.Minute % 15);

Console.WriteLine("{0:HH:mm}",rounded);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that round 15 to 30?