# How can I generate a list of datetime intervals that are in between two dates?

Tags: c#, loops, datetime

Let's suppose I have an interval. Say 15 minutes.

I have a start time of 13:57 and an end time of 15:17.

The time when this process runs happens to be 14:07.

I want the result to be 14:00,14:15,14:30,14:45,15:00,15:15 while retaining the year/month/date, etc.

So far, I have these facts down. The minutes modulo the interval is always zero. I need to count down from the current time until I hit the first mod-zero number which is 14:00.

I then simply increase that number by the interval until I reach my ceiling. My real question is how to come up with an elegant, simple way to find this first floor number.

The interval is a timespan and the other two values are datetimes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use solution from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029353/c-sharp-round-up-time-to-nearest-x-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the minute for the first result instance like:

```
m: current time's minute 
new minute part: m - (m % interval)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! After thinking about it for about 30 minutes, I hit myself on the head because I had forgotten about modulus. It's what I ended up using.