# Average int Array elements with a GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items like so:

[image]

Where each element in the list follows the same structure. Each `Y` property is an `int[]` which has 3 values.

I am then doing a `GroupBy` on this list to split the data up into 60 second periods:

```
var newChart = chart.GroupBy(x => x.DateAdded.RoundUp(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)));
```

`RoundUp` is an extension method I got from here: [How can I round up the time to the nearest X minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029353/how-can-i-round-up-the-time-to-the-nearest-x-minutes/7029464#7029464)

This creates a list like so, where the values are Grouped By the minute, which is what I'd expect:

[image]

So for example for the minute `20:18` there were 5 entries, this value may change, sometimes it may be 6 entries, sometimes 1 entry and so forth.

So my question is, how can I cast this new Grouped By list into the type of my original List where the `Y` values has the average of those entries in the group by. I've tried the following but the `Y` values contain more than 3 entries:

```
var newChart = chart.GroupBy(x => x.DateAdded.RoundUp(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)))
.Select(x => new ChartPoint
{
    DateAdded = x.Key,
    X = x.Key.ToString(@"HH:mm:ss"),
    Y = x.Select(y => (int)Math.Round(y.Y.Average(z => z), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)).ToArray()
});
```

[image]

So for example, if the entry at `20:18` had only 2 entries, and the Y values for entry 1 was: `3, 4, 5` and the values for entry 2 were: `5, 10, 11`. Then I would expect the entry at `20:18` for `Y` in this new list to be as follows: `4, 7, 8` because: `(3+5)/2 = 4`, `(4+10)/2 = 7`, `(5+11)/2 = 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the average for each array in the group, make a range that is the length of the arrays and get the average for the corresponding item from each array:

```
var newChart = chart.GroupBy(x => x.DateAdded.RoundUp(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)))
.Select(x => new ChartPoint
{
    DateAdded = x.Key,
    X = x.Key.ToString(@"HH:mm:ss"),
    Y = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => (int)Math.Round(x.Average(z => z.Y[i]))).ToArray()
});
```