# Sql aggregation to Linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I need to convert this query into linq to entities.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, ValueDateTime, 113) as MINUTE , avg(TagDataValue.TagValue) Value, TagName
FROM TagDataValue
WHERE ValueDateTime >= '6/03/2018' AND ValueDateTime < '6/06/2018' and TagName between ('Poll.Registers Block 0.310-TT-102_(6)') and ('Poll.Registers Block 0.310-TT-102_(7)')
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, ValueDateTime, 113) , TagName
```

I've tried couple of queries in linq to entities like this..

```
var g = (from x in ObjEntities.TagDataValues
                             where x.ValueDateTime >= FromDate && x.ValueDateTime <= EndDate && MachineName.Contains(x.MachineName) && ServerName.Contains(x.ServerName) && Tags.Contains(x.TagName)

                             select new
                             {
                                 TagName = x.TagName,
                                 MachineName = x.MachineName,
                                 ServerName = x.ServerName,
                                 TagValue = x.TagValue,
                                 DtTime = x.ValueDateTime
                             }).ToList().Distinct().GroupBy(t => new
                             {
                                 Date = t.DtTime.AddSeconds(-t.DtTime.Second % 60).AddMinutes(-t.DtTime.Minute % 60), //System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddHours(System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes(t.DtTime, -t.DtTime.Minute), -t.DtTime.Hour),
                                 TagName = t.TagName.Distinct(),
                             }).Select(u => new
                             {
                                 DateTime = u.Key.Date,
                                 Tagname = u.Key.TagName,
                                 tagvalue = u.Average(cd => cd.TagValue)
                             }).ToList();
```

but its not giving result, any idea how to write this into linq.

Comment: Why `Distinct`, does your model implement `IEquatable`, since you are not passing an `EqualityComparer` you would be better of calling `Distinct`, along wih EqualityComparer after Where clause

Comment: I did give try, but removing Distinct also didn't work for me.. :(

Comment: Then after that it would be Grouping issue, check what values are generated, since you are adding time (seconds / minutes), how would you expect to get any grouping data. First point remains whether Distinct leads to any value, if yes , then correct grouping values for data to be grouped

Comment: In my understanding `t.DtTime.AddSeconds(-t.DtTime.Second % 60).AddMinutes(-t.DtTime.Minute % 60)` will not match the value of `DtTime` also is `t.TagName` a collection to call Distinct, do you have IEquatable on the `TagName` type

Comment: no, basically, this is what I need to achieve, if you could help it will be very helpfull. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700293/aggregate-table-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: This is a DateTime range query, all that you need is `DateTime.ParseExact` with correct format and it shall yield the expected result, I don't see the scope of grouping here