# U-SQL + Pandas Merge_asof

Tags: python, pandas, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am working with Azure Data Lake Analytics for the first time and I am unsure how to merge 2 datasets like I would with pandas in python.

I am merging two datasets that have different timestamps but I need to line them up if they are within a specific timespan. This is straight forward in python.

Example python code: `pandas.merge_asof(trades, quotes, on='time', by='ticker', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2ms'))`

Full example can be found here: [click here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)

It seems like I can use python in my script however, I am not sure how I would get two datasets into the python function to do this merge.

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways of doing this. Using Python you can use the [Python reducer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-python-extensions) to go from U-SQL to Python. To run Python locally in ADL you will need to do some [additional steps](http://Install%20Azure%20U-SQL%20Extensions%20to%20run%20R/Python%20scripts%20locally?).

However I would recommend doing this in U-SQL. A quick way to do that would be to create a [rounded DateTime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029353/how-can-i-round-up-the-time-to-the-nearest-x-minutes) and then do an inner join on that:

```
@trades =
    SELECT *,
           // round up to nearest 2ms:
           new DateTime((time.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2).Ticks - 1) / TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2).Ticks * TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2).Ticks, time.Kind) AS RoundedTimeA
    FROM @trades;

@quotes =
    SELECT *,
           // round up to nearest 2ms:
           new DateTime((time.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2).Ticks - 1) / TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2).Ticks * TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2).Ticks, time.Kind) AS RoundedTimeB
    FROM @quotes;

@result = 
    SELECT *
    FROM @trades AS A INNER JOIN @quotes AS B ON
    A.RoundedTimeA == B.RoundedTimeB;
```